# Mail.php File configuration on HostGator Shared Hosting - Laravel

Tags: laravel-4, sendmail, shared-hosting

I have just hosted my website to the Hostgator shared hosting. But I'm getting error when I m sending the mail. Following is the code for it.

```
'driver' => 'smtp',

'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',

'port' => 587,

'from' => array('address' => 'info@marathon', 'name' => 'Radar'),

'encryption' => 'tls',

'username' => 'adorninfo10@gmail.com', // your@example.com  

'password' => '*******', //password

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

'pretend' => false,
```

This configuration was working fine on my localhost, But after uploading it to hostgator, it is not working anymore. What do I need to change in this?

Please help me in configuring this, Every help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

try the following

> change host to either your domain name or IP Address

instead of smtp.gmail.com.It should work give it a try :)

```
'host' => 'yourdomain.com'
```